# Line Breaks by Single Quotation in Python

Tags: python

I have this right now in Python:

```
"Going to school.
Taking a few courses and playing basketball.
Got a new puppy."
"Going to school.
I bought a new backpack yesterday.
Got a new cat.
I did my homework as well."
"Going to school.
Brought lunch today."
```

I am trying to figure out how I place line breaks in here from whenever `"` occurs so I have sentences that are in quotations on each line.

I think regex might be the way, but not certain. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extract the data within the quotes using `re.DOTALL` flag to consider endline like any other character, and use "non-greedy" mode

```
t = """"Going to school.
Taking a few courses and playing basketball.
Got a new puppy."
"Going to school.
I bought a new backpack yesterday.
Got a new cat.
I did my homework as well."
"Going to school.
Brought lunch today." """

import re

print(re.findall('".*?"',t,flags=re.DOTALL))
```

prints the list of extracted sentences, within quotes.

```
['"Going to school.\nTaking a few courses and playing basketball.\nGot a new puppy."',
'"Going to school.\nI bought a new backpack yesterday.\nGot a new cat.\nI did my homework as well."',
'"Going to school.\nBrought lunch today."']
```

Now that we extracted the data properly, joining that list of strings with linebreaks and replacing the inner linebreaks by spaces is easy now:

```
print("\n".join([x.replace("\n"," ") for x in re.findall('".*?"',t,flags=re.DOTALL)]))
```

output:

```
"Going to school. Taking a few courses and playing basketball. Got a new puppy."
"Going to school. I bought a new backpack yesterday. Got a new cat. I did my homework as well."
"Going to school. Brought lunch today."
```

Comment: So this is awesome, but I should have clarified more. What I am looking for is:

"Going to school . Taking a few courses. Got new puppy"
[line break]
"Going to school. Bought backpack. Got a cat."
[line break]
"Going to school. Brought my lunch." @Jean-François Fabre